# Automated github issue bot?

Tags: javascript, github

I would like to make a discord bot that creates an issue based on user input from discord. Any idea how I would do this? I am using JavaScript and would like to integrate it into an existing bot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can take ideas from the [`LeagueSandbox/IssueBot`](https://github.com/LeagueSandbox/IssueBot) (Typescript), which does create issues.

It does use [`npmjs.com/package/github-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/github-api), from [`github-tools/github`](https://github.com/github-tools/github)

```js
export class IssueCommand extends Command {
  execute() {
    if(!this.args) {
      return
    }
    let issueBody = ISSUE_TEMPLATE
      .replace("{PLACEHOLDER}", this.args[2] || "_No content_")
      .replace("{CHANNEL}", this.message.channel.name)
      .replace("{USER}", this.message.author.username)
    Bot.gitHub.api.issues.create({
        owner: config.githubName,
        repo: this.args[0],
        title: this.args[1],
        body: <any>issueBody // Typings for the `github` package are incorrect, so we have to cast to any here.
      },
      (error, response) => this.handleGithubResponse(error, response)
    )
  }

  handleGithubResponse(error, response) {
    if(error) {
      let formattedError = JSON.stringify(error, null, 4)
      let reply = ERROR_TEMPLATE.replace('{PLACEHOLDER}', formattedError)
      this.message.reply(reply)
      return
    }
    let reply = SUCCESS_TEMPLATE.replace('{PLACEHOLDER}', response.html_url)
    this.message.reply(reply)
  }
}
```

You have to [set up that bot in your Discord application](https://discordjs.guide/preparations/setting-up-a-bot-application.html#creating-your-bot).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe see the GitHub API docs for [Creating Issues](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/issues#create-an-issue)

You might need to create an app for it.